# How to rewrite the IIS web.config rewrite rules in nginx

Tags: nginx, iis, angular2-routing

We are moving current angular2 app from iis to nginx. Please help me in rewriting the following rules in nginx.

web.config

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Rewrite static files to content" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(?:\.css|\.js|\.html|\.eot|\.woff2|\.woff|\.ttf|\.jpg|\.png|\.gif|\.svg)$" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/{SCRIPT_NAME}" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="frontend">
            <match url="(?:\.css|\.js|\.html|\.eot|\.woff2|\.woff|\.ttf|\.jpg|\.png|\.gif|\.svg|\.txt|api/v1/Admin)" negate="true" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="index.html" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Nginix Config: 
This is my current nginx config file.

```
<code>
server {
  listen 80;
  sendfile on;
  default_type application/octet-stream;

  root /usr/share/nginx/html;
  location ~ \.css$ {}
  location ~ \.js$ {}
  location / {
        alias /usr/share/nginx/html/myplanningui/;
        try_files $uri$args $uri$args/ /myplanningui/index.html;
  }
  location /myplanningui {
        alias /usr/share/nginx/html/myplanningui/;
        try_files $uri$args $uri$args/ /myplanningui/index.html;
  }
  location /myplanningui/ {
        alias /usr/share/nginx/html/myplanningui/;
        try_files $uri$args $uri$args/ /myplanningui/index.html;
  }
}
</code>
```

Comment: Iis and nginx are very different in how they are configured. Post your nginx config and details of your web root structure.

Comment: @MisterSmith Thanks for the reply. Updated the niginx config file.